# Plone with pythonanywhere

Tags: python, plone

is there any way to develop a site with Plone on pythonanywhere? 
Because Plone to install need sudo operation and with pythonanywhere this is not possible.

Thank you,

John.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that pythonanywhere is not meant to host websites with high requirements such as Plone...

The `sudo` requirement that you mention though is not correct, you don't really need that in Plone, well, you do depending on how you install it.

If you are giving it a try you can use online demos: https://plone.com/try-plone

Of if you are into Docker, there are official images: https://hub.docker.com/r/plone/plone/

There is a heroku option as well: https://plone.org/download

There is also vagrant: https://plone.org/download/releases/5.1.1

And lastly, but maybe the more comprehensive of all, an ansible playbook: https://docs.plone.org/external/ansible-playbook/docs

Feel free to try any of them and report back your findings, either here in stackoverflow or in Plone community forums: https://community.plone.org/

Finally, if you are serious with Plone but lack skills you have professional Plone providers eager to help you out: https://plone.com/providers

Comment: Slight correction here -- PythonAnywhere is designed to handle any Python WSGI website, regardless of its requirements.   You just need to install them using the right flags: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules/

Comment: @GilesThomas then all the more, as Plone still has only experimental support for WSGI, it's coming, but is not production ready at all still

Comment: Gosh, really?   I didn't know that -- thanks for the correction!